# User is no longer logged in after redirect with React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, reactfire

I am trying to build an application with React and a Firebase server. However, I am having some issues with the authentication part.

To be more specific, here is the issue: I am able to successfully log the user in, but after I redirect the user to the homepage, the user is no longer logger in. Even if I remove the redirect from the function and I go to the homepage, I still get logged out after just a refresh of the page.

Here is the login function:

```js
LoginWithoutPromise: function(e, p){
      ref.authWithPassword({
          email: e,
          password: p
        },

        function(err, authData){
          if(err){
            console.log("Error logged in user:", err);
            window.location = "/";
          } else {
            console.log("Successfully logged in user account with uid:", authData.uid);
          }
        }
      );
  },
```

I have spent a whole afternoon trying to troubleshoot the issue but I ran out of ideas. I have the same problem even using the function provide within [this](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) awesome npm package.

Comment: EDIT: it seems like it has something to do with react-router as changing the history from hashHistory to browserHistory allows me to keep the users authenticated as long as they don't refresh the page.

Comment: It sounds like there is a page refresh. In that case you'll need to [monitor authentication state](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication). One of the packages you tagged and linked probably does that, but your code is not enough to reproduce the problem. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your support. As a matter of fact, I was dumb enough to have a logout function binded to an onClick on a stateless component that was loaded, which caused the function to run. I solved the issue replacing the onClick = {logout()} with onClick = {function(){logout()}}. I still can't wrap my head around some of the React logics.